Solving $2^{x+1} m -1=p^y$ for prime $p$ and natural $x,y$
Let $0<m\in\mathbb{Z}$ be odd, and consider the question of solvability of
$$
2^{x+1} m -1 = p^y,\quad\text{$p$ prime, } 0<x,y\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Is there always a solution? (I'm interested in the minimal possible $x$.)
A very limited testing on computer has not found any candidates for a counterexample. An outlier in the range $m<300$ was $m=191$, for it one needs $x=226$. Usually $x$ is much smaller.
PS. The first case which I can't resolve immediately is $m=659$. I went to $x=8500$ without finding a solution.
EDIT: $m=659$ is not a surprise, for the minimal $x+1=800516$, placing $2^{x+1}m$ beyond the reach of standard prime checking tools - one needs special techniques using Lucas sequences.

do you allow $y=1?$ It appears so.

yes, $y=1$ is allowed

For $m=659$, OEIS A040081 tells us that $2^{800516}m - 1$ is prime.

No, a counterexample (possibly not the smallest) is given by Riesel number $m=509203$.
We know that every number of the form $2^{x+1}m-1$ has a prime factor from the set $\{3,5,7,13,17,241\}$ and it remains to verify that those cannot serve as prime $p$ in the solution. To do so, we note that the congruence $2^{x+1}m-1 \equiv p^y\pmod{M}$ has no solutions for the following moduli $M$:

$170$ for $p=3$;
$62$ for $p=5$;
$342$ for $p=7$;
$210$ for $p=13$;
$30$ for $p=17$ and $p=241$.
QED


wow! NT is always full of surprises...
https://oeis.org/A040081/b040081.txt says that $2^{800516} 659-1$ is a prime power. How does one check this?
In your answer, what are these {3,5,7,13,17,241}, where do they come from?

@DimaPasechnik: Not just a prime power, but a prime. Primality tests for numbers of special forms like that are very fast - e.g. see https://t5k.org/prove/prove3_2.html and https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-143/S0025-5718-1978-0476625-0/

by the way, one can replace these $M$ with $M/2$.

@DimaPasechnik: It's very much possible. I did not aim at minimizing those moduli, they are just what my program yielded, which cares only about solubility and selects moduli of some special form.
